# Secure Ajax Connection with AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, security, https

Just started with AngularJS yesterday, so I'm yet not well oriented with the framework.

What's the best way to handle secure connections(https) with AngularJS? Maybe using it with the $http object is enough?

Comment: should work fine with `$http`.  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: No problem at all. Just want to make the security waterproof.

Comment: Don't spill anything on it, is my advice :)